# Problemas con caracteres especiales al generar LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, excel

Estoy cargando registros desde un Excel que convierto a TXT a una tabla en DB MySQL con **LOAD DATA**, mi problema es que convierte los caracteres con acentos o tildes a ? (caracter inspector) ya verifique la **COLLATION**

SERVER CONNECTION COLLATION

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

COLLATION DE LA TABLA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comprendo que si quiero mostrar los datos en una página web la tag meta debe ser **UTF8**

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? En el Excel todo esta correcto, ***Nuñez*** pasa del Excel a ***Nun?z*** a MySQL

Estoy cargado directo desde un TXT denominado "*CRMUNIV*" (delimitado por tabulaciones), primero hago todo en Excel posteriormente guardo como TXT (antes mencionado), la carga la realizo directamente desde Workbench con el "query":

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/CRMUNIV.txt'
INTO TABLE bujic_workspace.subcreditos
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Les dejo la definción de la tabla a la que quiero cargar los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Explica de qué manera estás pasando los datos a la BD: si mediante un comando ejecutado directamente, o si mediante código programado en PHP u otro. Indica también la definición de la tabla en la que quieres cargar los datos, para verla puedes ejecutar `SHOW CREATE TABLE aquiElNombreDeLaTabla;`

Comment: Listo @A.Cedano, una disculpa por no saber explicarme en la pregunta, espero ahora si me entiendas (an)

Comment: Se agradece que resultados que sean código lo pongas como texto, las capturas de imagen ayuda poco para estos casos. Por otro lado, ¿abriste el archivo `CRMUNIV.txt` en un editor de texto y has comprobado que los datos se ven bien en dicho archivo?

Comment: Asumiendo que los datos están correctos en el archivo, prueba a agregar el set de caracteres en la instrucción, algo así: `LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/CRMUNIV.txt' INTO TABLE bujic_workspace.subcreditos CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

Comment: Es problema al guardar de Excel a TXT ¿@A.Cedano tienes algúna idea como corregir esta parte?, corrí el query de la manera que me dices pero no funcionó

Comment: Puedes establecer el charset al momento de generar el `.csv` desde Excel, o bien abrirlo posteriormente con una aplicación tipo Notepad y darle a "Guardar como", estableciendo el charset utf8 o mediante un programa utilitario, dependiendo del sistema operativo.

Comment: Coloca tu último comentario comentario como respuesta para aceptarla como "correcta", de igual manera contestare mi propia respuesta con los paso que seguí para lograr mi objetivo, aclaro que sin tus comentarios no lo hubiera logrado ¡Gracias @A.Cedano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En muchos casos los `.csv` que se generan desde Excel dan problemas de codificación. Por ejemplo, a veces no es lo mismo un `.csv` generado desde Windows que uno generado desde Mac OS en cuanto a la codificación.

Para evitar este tipo de problemas, considera indicar desde Excel, al momento de generar el archivo, que lo quieres en la codificación `utf8`. A veces esto no es suficiente, por lo que conviene, para mayor seguridad, abrir el archivo en una aplicación tipo NotePad+ y guardar una nueva versión del archivo indicando explícitamente que lo quieres en codificación utf8. Esto lo puedes hacer también mediante programas utilitarios que cambian la codificación del archivo, pero esto ya depende de la plataforma.

Con esos pasos, y asegurándote de que en el entorno SQL tienes bien configurada la codificación, no deberías tener problema.

Por último, para más seguridad, indica el tipo de codificación en la instrucción que cargará los datos del archivo:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/CRMUNIV.txt' 
    INTO TABLE bujic_workspace.subcreditos 
    CHARACTER SET UTF8 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias amigo @A. Cedano!
A los que entren a revisar esta pregunta abajo respondi a mi propia pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Los siguientes pasos que describo, a mi me funcionaron para generar el "volcado" de manera correcta o bueno de la manera que necesitaba:

**Paso 1:**
Verificar que la "***SERVER CONNECTION COLLATION***" sea "***utf8mb4_general_ci***" así como el "***COTEJAMIENTO***" de la tabla sea "***utf8mb4_spanish_ci***".

**Paso 2:**
Tu documento ***Microsoft Office Excel*** guardalo como "***Texto (delimitado por tabulaciones)(txt)***"

*Nota: En la ventana que se abre para indicar donde guardar el archivo TXT, en la esquina inferior derecha (cerca del botón "Guardar") hay un menú desplegable en el selecciona la opción "Opciones web...", abrirá una ventana en ella en la pestaña codificación en el ajuste de "Guardar este documento como:" selecciona la opción "Unicode UTF-8", haces clic en "Aceptar" se cerrará la venta, posterimente ya puedes guardar el archivo TXT*

***Paso 3:***
Abre el archivo TXT que guardaste previamente (Paso 2) con el "***Bloc de notas***" (Recuerda que puedes abrir el Bloc de notas desde su icono o con CTRL + R en Ejecutar con "notepad").

**Paso 4:**
Cuando abras el archivo TXT, ahora desde el bloc de notas lo guardaras como otro archivo TXT desde "Guardar como" (CTRL + Mayús + S) se abrirá la ventana para indicar indicar donde guardar el archivo TXT, en la esquina inferior derecha (cerca del botón "Guardar") hay un menú desplegable con nombre "Codificación" en el seleccionar la opción "***UTF-8***" posterimente ya puedes guardar el archivo TXT.

***Paso 5:***
Ya cuando hayas realizado los pasos anteriores (1, 2, 3, 4) vamos a generar el volcado del archivo TXT hacía la tabla en la base de datos.

*Nota: Revisa que hayas creado tu tabla anteriormente y que el número de columnas coincida con el número de columnas de tu documentos de Microsoft Office Excel que volcaste a archivo TXT, de lo contrario puede que surgan problemas y/o errores*.

Vamos a generar el volcado a la tabla en la base de datos con la siguiente sentencia:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'direccion_del_archivo_txt'
INTO TABLE tabla_a_donde_volcar 
CHARACTER SET UTF8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

*Nota: Escribe la sentencia así como está, si no te puede dar error EOL, no olvides las comillas (A lo mejor tengo error de sintaxis en mi sentencia, pero me funciono, digo por si alguien quiere comentar con mejor sentencia)*

Paso 6:
Revisa que la información se haya volcado correctamente en la tabla deseada, generando una respectiva y sencilla sentencia SELECT, en caso de que haya funcionado **¡LISTO EL VOLCADO FUNCIONÓ DE MANERA CORRECTA!**
(Espero esto le sea util a alguien)

Answer (score 0):

La solución ideal sería guardarlo en formato utf8 para evitar el labor manual de abrir notepad, desde que tecnología estas guardando el archivo? nodejs? porque sería algo así:
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', 'utf8', callback);

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175144/how-to-set-file-encoding-in-node-js

Saludos!

Comment: De Microsoft Office Excel a TXT, aunque creo que ya logre solucionarlo, igual muchas gracias @Ricardo